# How to update all resulting models from a BookshelfJS collection?

Tags: bookshelf.js

Given for example, a list of products with an attribute of sold_out, I would like to update a field of every item in that collection.

In this particular example, let's suppose I want to set the field `sold_out = false` to all items with that field set as `true`:

```
Product.where({sold_out: true})
.fetchAll()
.then(soldOutCollection => {
  return Promise.all(product => {
    return product.save({sold_out: false})
  })
})
```

This works, but it triggers one query per item in the collection.

Is there any way to update all items at once (triggering just one query)?

PS: I'm trying to avoid using [knex.js](http://knexjs.org) directly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think if you want to update this way,  you might want to try this:

```
Product
.where({sold_out: true})
.save(
    {sold_out: false}, 
    {method: 'update', patch: true}
 )
```

Comment: does this run 2 queries - like first fetch the models in the Collection and then update them. Can't we directly update the multiple rows in Collection.

Comment: If I understand the Bookshelf API correctly the above will produce the following query:

`UPDATE product SET sold_out='false' WHERE sold_out='true' `


Basically doing one query to update them all.

Comment: Yes . Thank you for confirmation. I enabled the debug flag and verified.